# Can't connect to MariaDB from internal VM Structure

Tags: virtualization, tcp, xen, mariadb, tcpdump

S1

Virtual Machine 1: Ubuntu app server

Virtual Machine 2: MariaDB 1

S2

Virtual Machine 3: Ubuntu app server

Virtual Machine 4: MariaDB 2

from vm04 and 03 I can connect to DB1 with connection string with port 3306 but I can't connect DB2 from vm01 and 02

telnet can connect from 3306 to DB2

both of DB's MariaDB 10.6 and all of the VM's has got same configuration. VM03 can  connect to DB2.

When I listening to DB2 traffic with tcpdump I can see that the requests are arriving to DB but what happens after that I do not know exactly.

Any idea:

netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN | grep 3306

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5145/mariadbd
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      5145/mariadbd
```

edit:

error message of DB1

```
2023-02-27 12:32:17 5771 [Warning] Aborted connection 5771 to db: 'testdev' user: 'testuser' host: 'vm02' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
```

route -n (db2)

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         PublicIP        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.151   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

```
s1 192.168.2.0/24
s2 192.168.1.0/24
```

iptables

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --source 192.168.2.1/24 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --source 192.168.2.1/24 --dport 3307 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --source 192.168.2.1/24 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --source 192.168.2.1/24 --dport 3307 -j ACCEPT

same for 1.1./24 subnets
```

Comment: Please provide actual error messages you encounter.

Comment: And the routing tables and firewall configurations?

Comment: added route and iptables rules

Comment: another information: When use -A parameter on query I can login to server but I cannot see tables with "show tables". It is hanging but I can execute basic queries.